# view not found expressjs and deploying client-side js and css on expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, view, express

Here is my js file, which is in the same directory of my html file , I want to render it.

How hard can it be? I don't know what I am missing.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/'); //Edit #1

app.use(express.directory('public'));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   //res.send('hello world');
   res.render('gapijs.html');
});

app.listen(8090);
```

I used express.directory and express.static after reading expressjs docs(I am not sure it is right). I have all the deps installed and firmly linked in that directory. (using npm link )

**Edit:** I got to set views as mentioned in the comments by @Stan
After that, I got the same effect of res.write in vanilla node.

Here is another problem I am facing,How to deploy js and css files which are needed by gapijs.html and do I have to do anything to take care of js which I am downloading everytime I load the webpage?

**Edit 2:** here is my final version of code(which works the way I want).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   //res.send('hello world');
   res.render('gapijs.html');
});

app.listen(8090);
```

gapijs.html is in /public and js files public/js and css in public/css , the way js and css files are placed, when generating project using express command.

refer to those files from html as src="/js/blabla.js"

Comment: You need to set your views to be something like this: `app.set('views', __dirname + '/');`

Comment: You can put the JS and CSS files in the public directory and reference them as follows: `<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah, i need to put them in public directory and create a js folder for my javascripts(or directly refer the javascript file from the serving folder) and reference it as you said in my html.

Comment: @StanCromlish please post your comments(with liner explanation of app.set and app.use preferably) as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your views to be something like this:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
```

You can put the JS and CSS files in the /js and /css in **public directory** and reference them as follows, (as it is the convention):

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This should solve your issues.  Good Luck

Comment: /js/myjs.js works , if i put my js files in public/js folder. +1 though